# Best practice for where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Assume I have a table `Contract` of contracts with the following fields: `ContractId`, `ProductID`, `ProductType`. In the table for a same `ContractId` I have two possible `ProductID`. All the table is populated with two possible `ProductType` : `Type1` and `Type2`.

What would be the reason of doing the following query in one way or in the other?

Way 1:

```
 select c1.ProductID, c2.ProductID
 from Contract as c1 left join Contract as c2 on c1.ContractId=c2.ContractId
 where c1.ProductType <>'Type2'
```

Way 2:

```
 select c1.ProductID, c2.ProductID
 from Contract as c1 left join Contract as c2 on c1.ContractId=c2.ContractId
 where c1.ContractId not in (select ContractId from Contract where ProductType = 'Type2')
```

Thanks for your smart answers!

Comment: If `Contact`'s primary key is on `ContractId`, then your join to `c2` is useless. If `Contact`'s primary key isn't on `ContractId`, the two queries don't necessarily give the same results.

Comment: Actualy, ContractId is not the only column in the primary key. There are other columns I did not described here for easyness. But how would the two queries yield different results as ProductType can only be `Type1` or `Type2`? And what about efficiency?

Comment: Just try it: make sure you have `Contract` rows with the same `ContractID`, and some have `ProductType` `Type1`, some others have `ProductType` `Type2`. There's nothing meaningful to say about efficiency: it first has to be clear what your desired results are, and only then can you look for the most efficient way to get those results. Otherwise, I can make your query far more efficient by replacing it with `select 1`. It's faster than both your queries, but gives the wrong results, so is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Way 1 is both easier to read and easier for the DB engine to optimize.

Comment: Won't there be a case where query#2 will yield better performance?

Comment: @izambard Not that I can see. Performence for query#2 should be the same as, or worse than, query#1.

Answer (score 1):

Query #2 uses sub query and will be slow in performance than Query #1 which simply checks the condition without any further fetch from the table.